# How can a be smaller than 1 in recurrence relations?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, master-theorem

The general form of a decreasing recurrence relation is : **T(n)=aT(n-b)+f(n)**

E.g. **T(n)=T(n-1)+1** has the following pseudocode. Here *a*=1.

```
void rec(num)
{
   if(num>0)
   {
      printf(num);
      rec(num-1);
   }
}
```

And **T(n)=2T(n-1)+1** has the following pseudocode. Here *a*=2.

```
void rec(num)
{
   if(num>0)
   {
      printf(num);
      rec(num-1);
      rec(num-1);
   }
}
```

The Master's theorem for decreasing functions states that *if a<1*, T(n)=O(f(n)).
E.g. **T(n)=0.5T(n-1)+1** is a relation with *a*=0.5.

I want to ask how exactly can *a* be smaller than 1? What is some possible pseudocode for the above relation?

Comment: *"How can a be smaller than 1?"* Answer: it can't. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Inadmissible_equations

Answer (score 0):

A recurrence relation is just a neat mathematical description of (a class of) functions on ℕ  . Your example    `T(n)=0.5T(n-1)+1` is a perfectly valid reccurrence relation that has many solutions, e.g. `T(1) = 1, T(2) = 1.5, T(3) = 1.75, ..`, or, in general, T(n) = O(1)

The [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Inadmissible_equations) uses recurrence relations to describe the runtime of divide-and-conquer algorithms. In that case, `a` stands for  the number of subproblems in which the original problem is divided.

It is clear that that number has to be an integer > 0 for any non-trivial algorithm. In that context, `a=0.5` doesn't make any sense - it doesn't correspond to any class of algorithms or pseudocode.